# JButton takes entire frame

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I'm creating a login system and when I made my login button, it took up the entire frame. I tried the `.setBounds();` but it did not work. Not sure what I did wrong, please help.

```
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class Main extends JFrame{
      public Main(){
        JTextField name = new JTextField("Username");
        JTextField pass = new JTextField("Password");
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        name.setBounds(230, 110, 100, 25);
        pass.setBounds(230, 145, 100, 25);
        login.setBounds(230, 165, 100, 25);
        add(name);
        add(pass);
        add(login);
  }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
      Main a = new Main();
      a.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      a.setSize(500, 300);
      a.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      a.setVisible(true);
      a.setTitle("Login System");
      a.setResizable(false);
      a.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your constructor, try `setLayout(new FlowLayout());`.

This will likely not lead to what you want, but from there on you can investigate further. i recommend you read about layouts here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 1):

By default, Frame has a BorderLayout installed. When the items are added they are all added to "centre" because constraints are not passed. And the centre component occupies all free space in the BorderLayout. You can either change the layout manager or provide constraints while adding components.

FlowLayout or BoxLayout are good candidates for this.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is by default the layout manager for JFrame is BorderLayout. Once you add components with method `add()` it gets added to the center region. So the last component added is shown. In your case its the login button. Also `setBounds()` don't work with the said layout manager.

You have to work a lot on your coding style. What you did is first created the frame and added components to it and later in the `main()` you have set the size, made it visible and then you set the layout manager to FlowLayout.

Ideally, you must construct the frame, set layout, add components to frame, use pack() to set frame size, set frame's location and finally make frame visible.

Using BorderLayout:

```js
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main implements Runnable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Main());
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BorderLayout");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField(15), BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JPasswordField(15), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Login"), BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

[image]

Using FlowLayout:

```js
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main implements Runnable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Main());
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FlowLayout");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextField(15));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JPasswordField(15));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Login"));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

[image]

**P.S.** If you still want to use absolute positions, I would recommend you using SpringLayout or GroupLayout.

Comment: Thank you so much, but if I wanted to chose the positions of the fields and the button myself, would I use the "absolute layout"? Or is it just better to use the Flow and Border layout?